# Passing JSON from jQuery .getJSON to Python

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, json

I've been prepping for a potential move away from PHP and decided to use Python for my next project, I have managed to got myself completely stuck on something and I wonder if anybody could help me out.

If I perform:

```
$.getJSON('test.php', { testdata: 'hello world' })
```

In 'test.php' I can use

```
$_GET['testdata']
```

to retrieve 'hello world'.

I cannot seem to find the equivalent for test.py:

```
$.getJSON('test.py', { testdata: 'hello world' })
```

I have seen code posted online pertaining to request.get or os.environment to get the data but i have failed to make any configuration work. Would anybody have any suggestions?

I'm pretty new to development, so apologies if i'm missing out something obvious.

Kind thanks

Comment: How are you executing `test.py` on the server?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, apologies, I'm very new to all this. I have configured the server to use cgi as a handler for the meantime and chmoded test.py to 755. I'm running on the default apache and python builds that ship with osx lion if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works to me:

```
import cgi
import cgitb     #this...
cgitb.enable()   #..and this are not really necessary but helps debuging

data= cgi.FieldStorage()

#remove this commant to take a look in the data received by python
#print data

#here you can retrieve the value passed by ajax
print data['testdata'].value
```

I hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

[The `cgi` documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html) contains information on how to retrieve GET and POST variables in a Python CGI script.

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful - My aim was to get mod_wsgi running next, will field storage still be the right route in this case?