# Accessing POST variables in Python

Tags: python, ajax, post

I have this simple test AJAX request that sends data to a python script.

```
$.ajax({
              url: 'parser.py',
              type: 'POST',
              data: {test:"test"},
              dataType: "text",
              success: function(result)
              {
                console.log(result)
              },
              error: function(request, status, error)
              {
                console.log("oops")
              }
            })
```

I know it's quite simple, but how do I access the posted content that I send to the python script? Is it sent in a query string like PHP?

Comment: It depends on how your python script is executed. Usually people use WSGI-based frameworks in python which then provide GET and POST values in a framework-specific way.

Comment: This question has no answer unless you say how you're running that script.

Comment: I have gotten the results I wanted when using a test GET request to the python script, opening the URL to the API with urllib2, reading the XML and then parsing it. I wasn't completely aware I needed something additional for POST requests.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing JSON from jQuery .getJSON to Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10232327/passing-json-from-jquery-getjson-to-python)

Comment: This question helped solve mine: [Passing JSON from jQuery .getJSON to Python][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10232327/passing-json-from-jquery-getjson-to-python